# Android: Unreadable files - broken flash cells?

Tags: data-recovery, mtp

In the last month I noticed that more and more files on the internal data partition of my Android phone are broken. The files cannot be read via MTP and are empty when opened on the phone itself (e.g. grey pictures). As the number of "new" broken files increases I think that a part of the flash memory is broken.

1st: Is that a possible explanation? I would have expected flash controllers to hide broken cells automatically?!

2nd: Can I manually mark those sectors as bad sectors?

3rd: SATA-SSDs show how weared-down they are via SMART reporting - is there a way to check the quality of the flash cells within an android device?

Android is 4.4 CM 11.

Comment: If it doesn't mark the sectors as bad, it's a broken controller. Given that you are on CM11, I guess you are out of warranty. Do a nandroid backup of your device and get a new one.

Comment: How can I verify that? So far I only noticed broken files, not marking bad sectors is just one possible cause for this. For environmental reasons I usually stick to devices as long as possible.